# How can I execute a function before checkbox change takes place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, mouseevent

I'm having difficulty managing the order of event listeners on a checkbox input.

For example, if I have these inputs:

```
<input type='checkbox' class='multi' name='product' id='type1'>
<input type='checkbox' class='multi' name='product' id='type2'>
<input type='checkbox'               name='product' id='type3'>
```

I want to listen for whenever someone clicks an input with class = `.multi`, then execute two functions in sequence.

Specifically, I want `function(a)` to execute, **before** the change in checkbox status is registered (ie, before the check executes).

Right now, I have the following system that doesn't work, because the `change` event fires while the dialog box has been launched. I can't seem to pause the `change` event to wait until :

```
$('.multi').on('mousedown', function(a){ // open a jqueryUi dialog box and wait to complete function(a)
//do function(a) ...
$('.dialog').dialog('close');

then, once the dialog is closed...

 $(input:checkbox).on('change', function(b){ //do function b only after function a has completed
```

Comment: What if you just call function(b) from within function(a) and get rid of the change event handler? i.e. create a named function containing the code you have inside function(b) and then call it once you've done whatever you're currently doing in function(a).

Comment: @Chris I should have made it more clear that your option wouldn't work for me, as function(b) does other things which require it to be stand alone (in as much as I am able to figure things out with my limited coding experience!)

Comment: my guess is that you only need the on change, then inside that you test if the .multi class is present and if it is you start doing whatever the function_a was going to do, then continue with the rest of function_b, the only inconvenience I can think of is that the checkbox value will probably be the opposite that you want

Comment: Why do you insist on calling function_a before the change happening? What is function_a doing that depend on the change?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir It is somewhat convoluted, admittedly, but function(a) essentially modifies the contents of an array containing various strings, after which, function(b) uses the modified contents and sends it to a texarea. Depending on whether the dialog from the `multi` class has fired, the array is modified accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you looking for: (haven't tested it yet but this is what's on my head)

```
$('.multi').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    function(a); // your function
    $(this).trigger('click');
});
```

Good luck ^^

## Update:

Sorry, it seems the above code will do infinite recursion, try this:

```
$('.multi').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    function(a); // your function
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).prop('checked',false);
    } else {
        $(this).prop('checked',true);
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you meant to trigger the change event!

Comment: I think if the original event is 'click', then I paused it to call the preferred function, then I shall continue the 'click' by triggering the 'click' event. Unless the original event is $('.multi').on('change' ...
But the problem is that the 'change' event for checkboxes won't always work in all browser. (CMIIW)

Comment: Your code will create an infinite recursion. Click that triggers anther click that trig...

Comment: Your updated code worked perfectly for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you flow should be something like this:

1. checkbox change event
2. Open dialog box (modal)
3. dialog  (open callback ) invoke function a)
4. dialog (close callback) invoke function b)

e.g

Define dialog

```
 var dlgOptions={
     title:'My dialog',
     modal:true,
     buttons:{..},
     open:function(event, ui){
       //invoke function a
     },
     close:function(event, ui){
       //invoke function b
     }
    }
```

Then

```
$('.multi').on('change',function(e) {   
    $("#dlgSelector").dialog(dlgOptions)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do.

```
function functionB() {
    // Whatever you want to do here
}

// Initialise the dialog, specifying functionB as your callback function
// which will run automatically when the dialog closes.
$('.dialog').dialog({
    close: functionB
});

// Handle mousedown for any checkbox with 'multi' class
$('.multi').on('mousedown', function(a){
    // Do stuff...
    $('.dialog').dialog('close');
});

// Handle the 'change' event for any checkbox that DOESN'T have the 'multi' class
$(input:checkbox).not('.multi').on('change', functionB);
```

This way when you check a checkbox with the 'multi' class, it does its thing, then closes the dialog. Then, because we told the dialog to call functionB whenever it closes, functionB will execute.

And the other checkbox WITHOUT a 'multi' class can still call functionB independently on a 'change' event.